# How do I edit my CSP Header to allow inline Web Assembly (wasm)?

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy, webassembly

How do I modify this line of Nginx config to allow my website to serve and execute in-line Web-Assembly (wasm)?

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
```

Error Message:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at wasm-eval (“default-src”).
```

So, I basically just tried adding `wasm-eval` to my CSP, right before where it says `'unsafe-inline'`, but that didn't work. How do I edit my CSP Header to allow inline Web Assembly (wasm)?

Answer (score 2):

`wasm-unsafe-eval` appears to be the only CSP option that all modern browsers support

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_webassembly_execution

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but one solution is to add `'unsafe-eval'` to my CSP. So now the entire line of config looks like this:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
```

The above works, but maybe isn't great for security. Hopefully I can further update this question/answer in the future.